# Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm certainly no Ruby developer but I have an application on my server using Ruby, Gems, and Bundler. I am trying to install another Ruby on under a different user account but on the same VPS. When I go to run

```
bundle install
```

I get the following error:

> Could not locate Gemfile

I could remove the contents of the ./bundle directory so that all Gems are re-fetched to clear the error but will this have an impact on my other application using the same Gems and Bundler? I don't want to risk taking the other app down.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You do not have `Gemfile` in a directory where you run that command.
`Gemfile` is a file containing your `gem` settings for a *current* program.

Comment: Thanks. It was something this simple. I just had a problem because I had to be logged in as an admin user to run the command but the gemfile was in a directory under a different user. I managed to get it sorted. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you are right, if you use this command for install redmine, you should 'cd [redmine-directory]' then execute that command.

Answer (score 93):

Make sure you are in the project directory before running `bundle install`.  For example, after running `rails new myproject`, you will want to `cd myproject` before running `bundle install`.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the problem and I managed to get it sorted out in the end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and got it solved by using a different directory.

```
bash-4.2$ bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile
bash-4.2$ pwd
/home/amit/redmine/redmine-2.2.2-0/apps/redmine
bash-4.2$ cd htdocs/
bash-4.2$ ls
app  config db   extra  Gemfile   lib  plugins  Rakefile     script  tmp
bin  config.ru  doc  files  Gemfile.lock  log  public   README.rdoc  test    vendor
bash-4.2$ cd plugins/
bash-4.2$ bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.1) 
Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using activeresource (3.2.11) 
Using coderay (1.0.6) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.15.4) 
Using railties (3.2.11) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.3) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using net-ldap (0.3.1) 
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8) 
Using rack-openid (1.3.1) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using rails (3.2.11) 
Using rmagick (2.13.1) 
Your bundle i
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved similar problem just by backing out of the project directory, then cd back into the project directory and bundle install.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do `touch Gemfile`.

My case was an AWS Amazon Linux instance and Capistrano setting up Puma.

Answer (score 3):

Is very simple. when it says 'Could not locate Gemfile' it means in the folder you are currently in or a directory you are in, there is No a file named GemFile. Therefore in your command prompt give an explicit or full path of the there folder where such file name "Gemfile" is e.g cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\RubyProject\demo.

It will definitely be solved in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you could try.

Add this to any config files you use to run your app.

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
Bundler.require(:default)
```

Rails and other Rack based apps use this scheme. It happens sometimes that you are trying to run things which are some directories deeper than your root where your Gemfile normally is located.
Of course you solved this problem for now but occasionally we all get into trouble with this finding the Gemfile. I sometimes like when you can have all you gems in the .bundle directory also.
It never hurts to keep this site address under your pillow.
http://bundler.io/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to run locally checked out rails code in a script
`gem "rails", path: "../rails"`

Running the script normally as `ruby script.rb` gave the error `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)`

Setting the Gemfile path similar to [@douglasgallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207554/douglas-g-allen) solved it

`BUNDLE_GEMFILE="../rails" ruby script.rb`

Answer (score 0):

#### Typo

Maybe a stupid solution, but I got a typo: `Gemfile` instead of `GemFile`. Hope this helps.