# ROR Error: project directory contains "gemfile" but shows error "could not locate Gemfile" after executing bundle show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04

I am executing a command `rails new sample_app`. After creating a project `sample_app`, I executed `bundle show` command but it Could not locate Gemfile. 
[image]
I Google and found stackoverflow solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012181/bundle-install-could-not-locate-gemfile) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329953/could-not-locate-gemfile) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896137/could-not-locate-gemfile-after-executing-bundle-install) in which they didn't find `gemfile` whereas in my case i have. Suggest some solutions.

Comment: try bundle list.  "show=Show the source location of a particular gem in the bundle".  make sure it is Gemfile.  Also, run it within the app folder

Comment: What version of bundler have you got installed? bundle --version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be in sample_app directory. For this run on command prompt
    `cd sample_app`
then execute 
     `bundle install`
then 
      `bundle show`