# Going to project folder before "bundle install"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, rbenv

I'm trying to install jekyll based on instructions here (via rbenv): https://gist.github.com/r-brown/a0b50d56cfb3596e0d17

Before the "bundle install" step, it states:
go to the project folder

However, I'm new and simply truly confused as to what this refers to? I don't actually have a project folder right now, because I am merely in the process of installing jekyll?

Or is that referring to a specific location based on the earlier installation steps?

I attempted to skip this step and directly input `bundle install`, but that yielded this error

> "Could not locate Gemfile".

Referring to this post: [Could not locate Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329953/could-not-locate-gemfile) was unfortunately not useful as no one explicitly stated what "project folder" entails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use `jekyll`? Usually you would use it as part of a *project* - which probably entails writing the line:

```
gem 'jekyll'
```

...inside the `Gemfile` of your project. And then, to install the library (along with all other dependencies, you can run `bundle install`.

This is why the next line of the guide talks about running the command: `bundle exec jekyll serve ...` -- because the author is assuming that you have a project set up.

However, if you just want to install the gem globally (i.e. not within the context of a project), then you don't need to do anything with `bundle`. Just run:

```
gem install jekyll
```